# Appending to base image's ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The `microsoft/iis` image Dockerfile has this line:

`ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe", "w3svc"]`

In my image's dockerfile, which uses `microsoft/iis` as the base image, I have a powershell script which I would like to also run when the image runs as a container, so I have done this:

`ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "-executionpolicy", "bypass", "-command", "./my-script.ps1"]`

The desired result is that the `microsoft/iis` image would run its' `ENTRYPOINT`, followed by my image running its' `ENTRYPOINT`. However it seems that my image's `ENTRYPOINT` completely overwrites the `microsoft/iis` one.

How do I get both `ENTRYPOINT`s to run?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: Yes, I've accepted the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have multiple `ENTRYPOINT`s, but you could get this to work by putting both commands into a `start-up.ps1` and running that as your `ENTRYPOINT`.

```
ADD start-up.ps1

ENTRYPOINT ['powershell', '.\start-up.ps1']
```